# How to set wallpaper for all api's without stretching

Tags: java, android, image, api, wallpaper

I want to set the wallpaper by clicking a button. In [this example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-set-image-wallpaper-different-api-levels), how can I fix the stretching that occurs on api greater than 4 ? Also, is there another method to set the wallpaper for api older than 7? Because the `context.getWallpaper();` function seems to be deprecated, and the `WallPaperManager` class doesn't exist. Should I make a version of app with api < 4 and a version with api > 4 ?